# How can I load several 3D geometries in a separate thread without running into thread ownership issues?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading, xaml

I have several `MeshGeometry3D` elements that are stored in separate files. For example, `somemodel.xml` might contain `<MeshGeometry3D ... />`.

If I load them in the main UI thread, they lock up the UI while they load. So I've tried loading them in a separate thread:

```
ThreadStart threadStart = delegate
{
    var geometry = ConvertXmlFileToMeshGeometry3D(filename);
    viewport2DVisual3D.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
        DispatcherPriority.Normal,
        new Action(delegate { viewport2DVisual3D.Geometry = geometry; }));
};
threadStart.BeginInvoke(delegate(IAsyncResult aysncResult) { threadStart.EndInvoke(aysncResult); }, null);
```

However, this gives an exception on the line `viewportVisual.Geometry = geometry;`: `The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.`

In other words, the `MeshGeometry3D` was created on a different thread, so I cannot make it the `Viewport2DVisual3D`'s Geometry.

I can't figure out a way to asynchronously load the `MeshGeometry3D`s without them being owned by the wrong thread. Is this just something that is not possible, or is there a way to do it?

Edit: Profiling suggests that about 13% of the time to load a `MeshGeometry3D` is spent loading the xml element from the file (`var element = XElement.Load(filename);`), and the rest is spent converting it to a MeshGeometry3D:

```
return new MeshGeometry3D
{
    Normals = (Vector3DCollection)new Vector3DCollectionConverter().ConvertFromString(element.Attribute("Normals").Value),
    Positions = (Point3DCollection)new Point3DCollectionConverter().ConvertFromString(element.Attribute("Positions").Value),
    TextureCoordinates = (PointCollection)new PointCollectionConverter().ConvertFromString(element.Attribute("TextureCoordinates").Value),
    TriangleIndices = (Int32Collection)new Int32CollectionConverter().ConvertFromString(element.Attribute("TriangleIndices").Value),
};
```

So it doesn't look like fetching the XML from disk is the bottleneck here.

Comment: What is the operation that is "locking up" the UI? Is it the time spent fetching the XML from disk, or the time spent turning the XML into geometry objects, or what? (The reason I ask is because there might be some way to use task-based asynchrony to break up the work into smaller parts which could then be done in sequence on the UI thread but without starving the UI message loop.)

Comment: @Eric Lippert I think the issue isn't that the UI thread is blocking, but that WPF requires that certain operations be on the UI thread, which of course, can also cause the UI thread to block :)

Comment: @Eric: See my edit. According to my profiling, fetching the XML from disk and converting it to an `XElement` only takes about 13% of the total time to load a `MeshGeometry3D` from a file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless you need to modify the model later you can try to [`Freeze`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms557735.aspx) it after it has been loaded, then it can be shared accross threads, see [Freezable Objects Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750509.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, I don't need to modify the model later, so this works perfectly.